# Is it perfectly fine halachically to put up the schach first and then tie down the canvas walls?

Tags: sukkah, schach

If one has a sukkah with canvas walls that sway in the wind, can he put the schach on top of the sukkah before tying down the canvas walls so they won't sway, or would it be a problem of "Taaseh v'lo Min Haasuy"?

Comment: If you're machmir that the walls must not move at all (https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/preparing-sukkot-5777-qa/) then yes, this would be passul for the reason you mention. Others are more mekil and say the walls are only passul if they move 3 tefachim (e.g. Chazon Ish here https://www.etzion.org.il/en/walls-sukka), if so then you would be OK if your walls move less than this before being strapped down.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE not necessarily. You only need a tefach of wall (even at the top) to avoid taaseh velo min haasui. It may be that an unstrapped canvas wall could count for this purpose, even for those who are machmir to use the straps

Comment: @Joel K. I am sure you are right, but if we do not have kosher walls why is there no taaseh ve'lo min ha'sauy?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE See MB 635:11. Once you have walls of a tefach, it has already the status of an ohel, and the schach can be considered a sukkah. All that you’re doing afterwards is a tikkun  of the pre-existing walls

Comment: It is definitely a bidieved - https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-order-of-building-the-sukkah-setting-up-the-walls-before-the-sechach/

Comment: @JoelK it sounds like you have an answer to post; might I suggest you post it?

Comment: @msh210 I’m not certain that it is an answer. It’s possible that an untied canvas wall (for the machmir opinions) may not even count as a tefach of wall, which would mean a problem of taaseh velo min ha’asui. I suspect it depends on the practicalities: how much does the untied wall move near the point where it is attached?

Comment: @Joel K Thanks.